# Async/Await overkill? Am I unnecessarily using async and await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm wondering if my small node script is pointlessly or overdoing the use of async/await. My goal was to try to find and parse as many files in parallel as possible. My thoughts were it would faster.

My node script that walks through a directory and any child directories and looks for .docx files. When it finds them it runs them through [Mammoth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mammoth) converting them into .html files. It just places them in a similar directory structure.

My code works but am I overdoing it with the async/await? Are there spots where I can eliminate their use because there is no reasoning to be using them where I am?

```
const createTempDirs = async (catMap) => {
  try {
    const dirPromises = catMap.map((cat) => fs.mkdir(`issue/${cat.abv}`, {
      recursive: true,
    }));
    await Promise.all(dirPromises);  
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const writeToFile = (fileName) => {
  return async (result) => {
    //return await fs.writeFile(`issue/${fileName.replace('.docx', '.html')}`);
    try {
      const [
        ,
        category,
        ...parts
      ] = fileName.split(' ');
      await createTempDirs(catMap),
      await fs.writeFile(`issue/${getShortCatName(category)}/${fileName.replace('.docx', '.html')}`, result.value);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
}

const fileToHTML = async (file, dirPath) => {
  try {
    const fileDetails = await fs.lstat(dirPath + file);
    if (fileDetails.isDirectory()) {
      walkDir(dirPath + addTrailingSlash(file));
    }
    if (!fileDetails.isDirectory() && path.extname(file) === '.docx') {
      mammoth.convertToHtml({
        path: dirPath + file,
      }, conversionOptions).then(writeToFile(file));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const processFiles = async (files, dirPath) => {
  try {
    const filePromises = files.map(file => fileToHTML(file, dirPath));
    return await Promise.all(filePromises);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const walkDir = async (dirPath) => {
  try {
    const files = await fs.readdir(dirPath);
    processFiles(files, dirPath);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

walkDir(dirPath);
```

Comment: The main problem I see is all the `try`/`catch`es. What exactly do you want to happen when there's an error? Do you want the current file parsing to stop, or the current directory parsing to stop, or the whole script to stop, or what?

Comment: @CertainPerformance In trying to get familiar with async/await every resource I've read seems to reiterate the same point and that's to always use try/catch when using async/await. But perhaps in being new I'm reading it wrong and overdoing it when I don't need too.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to happen when you encounter an error?

Comment: The advice on try/catch when using async/await is closer to “never” than “always”.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Until I get more familiar I was just going to log them. The overuse of them is just do to my misunderstanding I guess.

Comment: @Ry- Thanks for the feedback, I'll reevaluate my use perhaps I was misunderstanding what I was reading.

Comment: Aside from logging, what is the *operational logic* you're looking for when an error happens? Continue on as if nothing happened? Stop everything? That's what the refactoring depends on

Comment: @CertainPerformance They don't really have any operational logic right now. It would be nice to act on the errors though. Perhaps stop operation and prompt for a valid directory, or let the user know if no .docx files were found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` is generally useful when a particular block of code needs to wait for a Promise *and then do something with it* before finishing (possibly involving awaiting *another* Promise afterwards). If the only `await` is on the last real line of the function, it makes much more sense to just return the Promise.

As for `try`/`catch`, the general idea is to catch errors *at the level that they can be appropriately handled*. So, for example, if you want to stop completely when there's a problem, *only* `catch` in the outermost call, like:

```
const createTempDirs = (catMap) => Promise.all(
  catMap.map((cat) => fs.mkdir(`issue/${cat.abv}`, {
    recursive: true,
  }))
);

const writeToFile = (fileName) => {
  return async (result) => {
    //return await fs.writeFile(`issue/${fileName.replace('.docx', '.html')}`);
    const [
      ,
      category,
      ...parts
    ] = fileName.split(' ');
    await createTempDirs(catMap);
    await fs.writeFile(`issue/${getShortCatName(category)}/${fileName.replace('.docx', '.html')}`, result.value);
  };
};

const fileToHTML = async (file, dirPath) => {
  const fileDetails = await fs.lstat(dirPath + file);
  if (fileDetails.isDirectory()) {
    // see below line - remember to await or return every Promise created!
    await walkDir(dirPath + addTrailingSlash(file));
  }
  if (!fileDetails.isDirectory() && path.extname(file) === '.docx') {
    // see below line - remember to await or return every Promise created!
    return mammoth.convertToHtml({
      path: dirPath + file,
    }, conversionOptions).then(writeToFile(file));
  }
};

const processFiles = (files, dirPath) => Promise.all(files.map(file => fileToHTML(file, dirPath)));

const walkDir = async (dirPath) => {
  const files = await fs.readdir(dirPath);
  processFiles(files, dirPath);
};
```

Then, only `catch` in the entry point, the call of `walkDir`:

```
walkDir(dirPath)
  .catch((err) => {
    // There was an error somewhere
  });
```

If you want to keep processing at a certain point when there's an error in a sub-call, then catch the error at that point, eg if a single `writeFile` can fail, but you don't want the error to percolate up the call chain and stop everything, `try/catch` in the caller of `writeFile`:

```
const writeToFile = (fileName) => {
  return async (result) => {
    const [
      ,
      category,
      ...parts
    ] = fileName.split(' ');
    await createTempDirs(catMap);
    try {
      await fs.writeFile(`issue/${getShortCatName(category)}/${fileName.replace('.docx', '.html')}`, result.value);
    } catch(e) {
      // writeFile failed, but the rest of the script will continue on as normal
      // the error, since it was caught here,
      // WILL NOT BE passed up to the caller of writeToFile
    }
  };
};
```

Make sure to `await` or `return` every single Promise you create past the entry point, so that errors will be passed up the Promise chain properly. (see the fixes made to `fileToHTML`)